# how to set up CURL ngrok using php?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, ngrok

the problem is showing like this: `ERR_NGROK_3200   Tunnel hostname not found`

[image]

how to set up properly CURL for ngrok using PHP (Laravel)?

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `python` as this is one of tags you have used

Comment: Sorry, my bad I didn't notice it.

Comment: Is your tunnel URL still valid? If you are using the free version of ngrok, those expire after a certain time (I think 8 hours or something.)

Comment: Hi @NeverStopLearning, welcome to Stack Overflow, please share your PHP code into a code snipped, with it, we can help you better and your question will follow the recommended format, please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#Help%20others%20reproduce%20the%20problem)